# In "property dualism", what is the subject of experience?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

Within property dualism... is the subject of experience the brain itself? Or is the subject of experience another property of the brain (like the contents of experience are)?

Comment: A property can not be a subject, it has to be a substance. But remember that dualists admit non-physical properties, so "the brain itself" as we usually think of it, i.e. a purely physical abstraction of what is really there, is not the subject either. Just as objects are not material points by which mechanics represents them. The subject is the X of which the brain (and the rest of the nervous system, presumably) is a physical manifestation and the mind (and the rest of the psyche, if that is broader) is a mental one.

Comment: "The subject is the X of which the brain"... Can you elaborate on what you mean here?

Comment: Just as the object is the actual body, not a material point. We just do not know what the metaphysical substrate of brain/mind is, hence X.

Comment: But don't the property dualists say the substrate is "physical" in nature?

Comment: It can not be "physical" in full sense and have non-physical properties. "Physical" merely means that it has a physical aspect, and is not a free floating spirit.

Comment: Interesting...that makes perfect sense to me, but in every description of property dualism I see online... it refers to a "physical" substance with "physical" and "mental" properties. That gives the impression that the "physical" aspect is more important or fundamental than the "non-physical" aspect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106976/discussion-between-ameet-sharma-and-conifold).